# TextView.onRestoreInstanceState() doesn't work

Tags: android, persistence

My app needs to be able to dynamically create `TextViews`, so I need to be able to restore them if my app is ever GCed or switches orientations. The problem is I can't figure out how to restore the state of my `TextViews`. Saving their states with `TextView.onSaveInstanceState()` seems to work just fine, but when the `Parcelable` is passed to `onRestoreInstanceState()`, nothing happens and the resulting view is just blank. This is a short example which doesn't work:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView v;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewGroup main = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main);
    v = new TextView(this);
    main.addView(v);

    if (state == null) {
        v.setText("A simple message.");
    } else {
        v.onRestoreInstanceState(state.getParcelable("message"));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("message", v.onSaveInstanceState());
}

}
```

I have checked the value of `state.getParcelable("message")` in the debugger and it definitely has the required information. `onRestoreInstanceState()` just isn't using it. Any help at all would be appreciated.

EDIT: I screwed up with the debugger. The information was actually never written to the bundle. `TextView.onSaveInstanceState()` had returned an empty Parcelable. That was the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It the problem was with `TextView.onSaveInstanceState()`—not `TextView.onRestoreInstanceState()`. `TextView.onSaveInstaceState()` only saves the state if you explicitly ask it to by calling `TextView.setFreezesText(true)` first. *SURPRISE!* Thank you, Google. Also note that onRestoreInstanceState() doesn't restore the FreezesText property. Oh, Google. You're just so zany. What'll we do with you?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of restoring the state during `onCreate()` you may choose to implement `onRestoreInstanceState()`, which the system calls after the `onStart()` method. The system calls `onRestoreInstanceState()` only if there is a saved state to restore, so you do not need to check whether the Bundle is null:

Save Your Activity State:

```
static final String STATE_SCORE = "playerScore";
static final String STATE_LEVEL = "playerLevel";

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Restore Your Activity State:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // Always call the superclass first

    // Check whether we're recreating a previously destroyed instance
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
        mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
    } else {
        // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
    }

}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
    mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
    mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
}
```

Comment: The problem is specifically with restoring textview states from a Parcelable. The same problems would come up if I did it by overriding onRestoreInstanceState().